# How to retrieve response-headers from a cross-domain HEAD request from my cross-browser addon?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, browser-extension, kango-framework

I am using Kango framework to develop a cross-browser addon, using the following code I am making `HEAD` request's utilizing [Kango.XHR](http://kangoextensions.com/docs/api-reference/kango-xhr.html#kango-xhr) which is getting successfully executed (as shown in HTTP DEBUGGER) and the code below in my background script also returns `data.status == 200`.

```
function doXHR(url) {
var details = {
    method: 'HEAD',
    url: url,
    async: true
};


kango.xhr.send(details, function(data) {
    if (data.status == 200) {
        kango.console.log(data.status);
    }
    else { // something went wrong
        kango.console.log('something went wrong');
    }
});
};
```

Now, I want to get the value of `Content-Length` response header from the above but have no clue how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordinarily, you can read response headers with [`xhr.getReponseHeader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#getResponseHeader%28%29). Depending on how Kango works, that method may already be available on your `data` object.

If `data.getReponseHeader("Content-Length")` doesn't work, then instead of using `kngo.xhr.send`, you might try imitating a normal Ajax call with [`kango.getXMLHttpRequest`](http://kangoextensions.com/docs/api-reference/kango-xhr.html#getxmlhttprequest):

```
var request = kango.xhr.getXMLHttpRequest();
request.open('HEAD', url);
request.send(null);
request.onload = function() {
    if(request.status == 200) {
        console.log(request.getResponseHeader("Content-Length"));
        console.log(request.responseText);
    }
}
request.onerror = function() {
    console.log("something went wrong");
}
```

Again, depending on how Kango operates under the hood, your server might need to serve an [Access-Control-Expose-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Expose-Headers) response header to allow the client to read it. This won't likely be necessary, since extension code usually is not bound by the same origin policy, but I offer it only to help you iron out any possible inconsistencies in Kango's cross-platform API.

Comment: That worked like a charm, however I am having problem passing the retrieved value from bg script using `function doXHR(url) {
 var request = kango.xhr.getXMLHttpRequest();
 request.open('HEAD', url);
 request.send(null);
 request.onload = function () {
  if (request.status == 200) {
   
   return request.getResponseHeader("Content-Length");
   
  }
 };
 request.onerror = function () {
  kango.console.log("Check url, something went wrong");
 }
};` to caller in content-script `kango.invokeAsync('doXHR', url, function (size) {
     kango.console.log(size);
     
    });`?